# How to add bearer token to retrofit request in Java

Tags: java, testing, cucumber, retrofit2, web-api-testing

Hi Im trying to add a bearer token to a retrofit call in java, but i cant seem to pass it.

Currently Im logging in with one method and this creates a bearer token and im trying to add the token to the Get Call, but its just returning a 401 error, have I added the token to the call correctly?

```
@GET("diagnosis/configuration")
Call<ResponseBody> getFavourites (@Query("favourite") Boolean fave,@Header("Bearer Token") String authHeader);

@POST("auth/login")
Call<LoginResponse> postLogin (@Body LoginCredentialsBody body);



public class LoginApiStepDefinition extends TestBaseFix {

Retrofit retrofit = super.buildRetrofit(super.buildOkHttpClient());
RetrofitCallsLogin call = retrofit.create(RetrofitCallsLogin.class);
RetrofitCallsGetFavourites favecall = retrofit.create(RetrofitCallsGetFavourites.class);

private Response<LoginResponse> responseBody;
private String favouritesResponseBody;


String usernameValue;
String passwordValue;


@And("I login with {string} and {string} to return login token")
public void iLoginWithAndToReturnLoginToken(String username, String password) throws Exception {

    LoginApi(username, password);

}


public String LoginApi(String username, String password) throws Exception {


    usernameValue = username;
    passwordValue = password;

    //gets fixture ids for the dates
    LoginCredentialsBody login = new LoginCredentialsBody();
    login.setPassword(passwordValue);
    login.setUsername(usernameValue);
    String responseBody = call.postLogin(login).execute().body().toString();
    String requiredString = responseBody.substring(responseBody.indexOf("=") + 1, responseBody.indexOf(","));


    System.out.println(requiredString);


    return token;


}



@Then("I get the list of favourites with {string} and {string}")
public void iGetTheListOfFavouritesWithAnd(String username, String password) throws Exception {

    String favouritesResponseBody = favecall.getFavourites(true, LoginApi(username, password)).execute().body().toString();
    System.out.println(favouritesResponseBody);
}
```

}

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To add bearer token in retrofit, you have to create a class that implements `Interceptor`

```
public class TokenInterceptor implements Interceptor{

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
   
       //rewrite the request to add bearer token
        Request newRequest=chain.request().newBuilder()
                .header("Authorization","Bearer "+ yourtokenvalue)
                .build();

        return chain.proceed(newRequest);
    }
}
```

Now add your Interceptor class in OKHttpClient object and add that obejct in Retrofit object:

```
TokenInterceptor interceptor=new TokenInterceptor();

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(interceptor)
            .build();

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .client(client)
            .baseUrl("add your url here")
            .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, although how do I add this to my current methods (apologies im very new with retrofit)

Comment: you should add bearer token in request header instead of request body

Comment: Does @Header not add the bearer to the header?

Comment: Yeah It does add header but you have added "Bearer token" it is incorrect

Comment: Are you using JWT? if yes then you have to use Authorization keyword

Comment: Ive changed the call to this but it still isnt adding it: Call<ResponseBody> getFavourites (@Query("favourite") Boolean fave, @Header("Bearer") String authHeader);

Comment: Why are you not using "Authorization" keyword it's mendatory if you are communicating using token

Comment: Where does authorization get added in this?

Comment: Try to add this: (@Header("Authorization") String finaltoken) where finaltoken will be "Bearer "+yourtoken

Comment: I added that, but now its just returning unauthorized, I actually tried using the authorization header in Postman and that returned Unauthorized aswell, the only way it authorizes me in postman is if i select Bearer in the Authorization section

Comment: can you please tell me which authorization method are you using? because header depends on that

Comment: I tried changing the header to "Bearer " and it returned java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unexpected char 0x20 at 6 in header name: Bearer

Comment: Ive added a screenshot of the Bearer token that we use

Comment: If you add @header in retrofit then it will be added in header section of postman

Comment: check out this:https://android.jlelse.eu/token-authorization-with-retrofit-android-oauth-2-0-747995c79720

Comment: They said same as i said that add (@header("Authorization) finaltoken) where finaltoken will be "Bearer "+token value. Add this in your Postman header section- key:Authorization and value will be "Bearer yourtoken"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212364/discussion-between-bhoomi-vaghasiya-and-fearghalqa).

Answer (score 1):

these three class will be your final setup for all types of call

> for first call(Login) you do not need to pass token and after login pass jwt as bearer token to authenticate after authentication do not need to pass

```
public class ApiUtils {
private static  final String BASE_URL="https://abcd.abcd.com/";
public ApiUtils() {
}

public static API getApiService(String token){
    return RetrofitClient.getClient(BASE_URL,token).create(API.class);
}}
```

2.Using ApiUtils.getapiService you can get the client ,pass jwt or bearer token

```
public class RetrofitClient {
public static Retrofit retrofit=null;
public static Retrofit getClient(String baseUrl, String token){
    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .readTimeout(60,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .connectTimeout(60,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .addInterceptor(interceptor)
            .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @NotNull
        @Override
        public Response intercept(@NotNull Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request request=chain.request().newBuilder()
                    .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
                    .build();
            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    }).build();
    if(retrofit==null||token!=null){
        retrofit= new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}}
```

3 In this Interface you can create methods for get or post requests

```
public interface API {

@POST("/Api/Authentication/Login")
Call<JsonObject> login(@Body Model userdata);

@POST("/api/Authentication/ValidateSession")
Call<JsonObject> validateSession(@Body MyToken myToken);

@POST("/api/master/abcd")
Call<JsonObject> phoneDir(@Body JsonObject jsonObject);

@Multipart
@POST("/api/dash/UploadProfilePic")
Call<JsonObject> uploadProfile(@Part MultipartBody.Part part);

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/api/dashboard/RulesAndPolicies")
Call<JsonObject> rulesAndProcess(@Field("ct") int city);

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/api/dashboard/RulesAndPolicies")
Call<JsonObject> rulesAndProcess(
        @Field("city") int city,
        @Field("department") String department,
        @Field("ctype") String ctype
);
```

Comment: IMHO if(retrofit==null||token!=null) Should be if( retrofit == null || token == null)
Also, is this tested? seems like you may get Exception while creating the `client` if the token is null

Comment: No , you will not get exception for the first call we dont need token so you can pass null